# Should we put all css inside HTML document?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a Site enhancement.
The Bootstrap.min.css took 0.5 second to load complete to our website.

I thinks solve the 0.5 by place all minified CSS in my HTML Document (In production mode). It's a good idea for run-time enhancement ? Does it make HTML Engine slow to load the CSS ?

Comment: now you've bumped up the size of your html document by the size of all that css, and have to do that for EVERY page, meaning you're sending out a ton of duplicate css that cannot be cached/shared

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your page. Besides a zillion of factors that influence the page speed, two factors are most important in regards to your question.

- bandwidth
- amount of requests

If you have one of those single page angular websites for example, then putting all css into your html makes sense. This will reduce the amount of requests, while the bandwidth consumption stays the same.

If you have a "normal" website, with the user loading a new html page every time he clicks on a link, then its better to put the css into .css files, so he doesnt have to load the same information over and over again. This will increase the amount of requests, while dramatically reducing the bandwidth consumption (because of browser side caching of the css).

If you want to increase the speed of your website, look into caching, CDN's and tools like those explained here, which will guide you into the right direction: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/